# iOS Application wants to load Mono.Andoid

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, mono

I have a Xamarin.Forms Application which is running on Android. Now I want to make it work on iOS.
When I try to run it on the iOS simulator with the connected Mac, I get the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load the file
>   'Mono.Android'.'

It happens when the

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
```

is executed in the FinishedLaunching method.

I found nothing in the web what helps me.
I deleted the bin and obj folders, cleaned the solution and updated all nuget packages, but nothing helped.
Why is the iOS app trying to load Mono.Andoid, is that a right behavior?

Any help appreciated

Comment: have you checked that your iOS and shared projects are not directly referencing Android?

Comment: How can I check that? Sorry if this is a dumb question but I only worked with Android in the past.

Comment: If you're in VS you can go to your iOS project, click on Dependencies drop down arrow, and then the projects drop down and see if any of them reference Android